# Почему css игнорирует !important?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему свойство, которое, мало того, записано позже основного, так ещё и с !important, игнорируется в конечном итоге?

Comment: Очевидно потому что там ##

Comment: на треугольник наведите ))) он же не просто так там

Comment: @Vearodev о Господи, точно, как я мог не заметить)) Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно:
background: #96BEFF !important;

А не:
background: ##96BEFF !important;

**Syntax error**